# Solving the simultaneous equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to solve the following simultaneous equations for the constants $A$ and $B$:

$$zA + (1-z)B = 1$$
$$\hspace{1.8cm} z^2A + (1-z)B = z^2 - z + 1$$

where$z$ is just a variable. What I did was this:

$$zA = 1 - (1-z)B \implies z^2A = z - (z - z^2)B$$

and so subbing this into the second equation gives me

$$z - (z - z^2)B + (1-z)B = z^2 -z + 1$$

Rearanging gives me

$$(z^2 - 2z + 1) = (1 - z)^2 = \{(1-z) - z(1 - z)\}B $$

which can then be simplified to get

$$(1 - z) = (1 - z)B \implies B = 1$$

which is wrong beacuse in my answers it says $B = \frac{1-z}{1 - 2z}$. I think I will get $A$ once I have $B$ but I can't see my mistake right now.

Comment: I think A and B both value should be 1 because when I put it on both eqn it gives LHS=RHS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

From eq. (1):

$$(1-z)B=1-Az$$

From eq. (2):

$$(1-z)B=(1-A)z^2-z+1$$

so

$$ (1)=(2)\implies (1-A)z^2-(1-A)z=0\implies A=1\;\; \text {or} \;\,\,z(z-1)=0\;\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

You system has infinitely many solutions if $A=B=1$ (for instance, substract the second from the first, and see what happens to $A$). Then, any $z$ satisfies it.

If $A\neq1$, then $z$ must be either $0$ or $1$. But plugging $z=1$ in the equations yields $A=1$, so the only solution is $z=0$.